# What prayers and psalms are read during shmira near the body of the deceased?

Tags: tefilla, death, tehilim-psalms, funeral-burial-levaya

Of particular interest are the prayers and the order of reading the psalms in Nusach Ashkenaz.

Answer (score 1):

So in the [Nitei Gavriel on Aveilus (cheilek alef), chapt 10](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46539&st=&pgnum=86&hilite=) it lists the halachos of those doing shemira. The following points are pertinent to your question:

- (ois alef) One who is doing Shemirah is exempt from krias Shemah and any tefillah. (Refer to [SA OC 71:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.71.3?ven=Sefaria_Community_Translation&vhe=Maginei_Eretz:_Shulchan_Aruch_Orach_Chaim,_Lemberg,_1893&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), [SA YD 341:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.341.6?ven=Code_of_Hebrew_Law_by_Chaim_N._Denburg,_Montreal,_1955&vhe=Ashlei_Ravrevei:_Shulchan_Aruch_Yoreh_Deah,_Lemberg,_1888&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and [SA YD 403:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.403.9?ven=Code_of_Hebrew_Law_by_Chaim_N._Denburg,_Montreal,_1955&vhe=Ashlei_Ravrevei:_Shulchan_Aruch_Yoreh_Deah,_Lemberg,_1888&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)). Therefore one can arrange, if possible, that there be two shomrim, so that one can guard whilst the other goes and says Shemah and davens. This idea I also saw brought down in the [first cheilek of Gesher HaChaim, perek hei](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=31174&st=&pgnum=51&hilite=).
- ([ois ches](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46539&st=&pgnum=89)) Even though it is forbidden to to daven and say divrei Torah in front of the deceased, it is permitted to say tehillim. (This idea is also brought in Gesher HaChaim linked above). Even an [onein](https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Onen) can say tehillim (this is further elaborated later [here](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46539&st=&pgnum=133&hilite=) (ois gimmel)) as they are doing it to respect the deceased. However others are stringent since an onein by definition is patur (exempt) from doing any mitzvos.

So to answer your questions. General tefillos are avoided unless there is someone else there with you so that you can go and daven elsewhere whilst they guard. And as far as tehillim, one can recite (and I have read elsewhere that it is encouraged) but there is no set standard or formal selection.

However there is sefer which is cited by both the Nitei Gavriel and Gesher HaChaim entitled [Ma'avar Yabok](https://hebrewbooks.org/14051) by [Rabbi Aharon Berachia of Modina](https://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/20-aaron-berechiah-ben-moses-ben-nehemiah-of-modena) which provides select sections from throughout tanach (incl. Tehillim) that one can work through.

Comment: You did not answer my question. I asked about specific chapters of Tehillim and prayers, but for some reason you told me about halachot of shemira.

Comment: The first two bullet points spell out the important background knowledge that one is exempt from prayers but one can say tehillim. and the third paragraph then answers the point....

Comment: Your question asked "What prayers and psalms are read during shmira" - firstly I proved that no "prayers" are said.

Comment: What chapters of Teilim are read during shemira, according to Nusach Ashkenaz? I didn't find any information available!

Comment: Exactly, as per my point - "one can recite (and I have read elsewhere that it is encouraged) but there is no set standard or formal selection"

Comment: Then what variants are most common in Ashkenazi minhag? I'm sorry for my meticulousness, but your answer sounded like: "Why do you need these traditions? Read what you want!".

Comment: You keep missing what I'm saying. There is no inherent tradition - you can pick up a tehillim and select whatever you want. Feel free to ask a Rov as to which ones will be the most meaningful to you. If it is anything like visiting a kever - some people work through tehillim 119 (which each stanza is arranged according to the letters of the alef beis) and spell out (i.e. say the relevant letter) of the niftar's full Hebrew name.

Comment: Then why do some communities have a clear tradition of reading Psalms 23, 90:17 and 91? That's why I'm interested in other options.

Comment: What does it mean 90:17? They say just that one posuk?

Comment: Yes. https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/367830/jewish/Selected-Psalms-to-Be-Recited-in-the-Presence-of-the-Deceased.htm

Comment: Interesting - never seen that before. Please note it does say "One can also recite additional Psalms" - i.e. non-specific ones

Answer (score -1):

The ten Tehillim of Tikkun haKlali (16 32 41 42 59, 77 90 105 137 150, to be read in that sequence that they occur) are always appropriate and especially at Shemira. It is "The General Remedy." (As explained in Likutei Moharan #29 and other places).